# Disabling parent page while displaying MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created an alert using MessageBox.Show method. But I'd like to forbid the editing of the controls in the page which is still accessible behind the messagebox. If I try to disable every control manually before firing the messagebox the controls are disabled only after picking a choice in the messagebox.

Please Help :)

Comment: Are you actually using asp.net, or WinForms?  You should never use MessageBox.Show() in asp.net.  The client won't see it, as that code runs on the web server.

Comment: I'm using asp.net. Now i think you're right, messagebox.show only runs on the webserver. So how can I reproduce a javascript window.confirm on server side?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way to do what I need.

You can add an "onclientclick" event to the button you want to fire the Confirm Popup.

```
<asp:Button id="Button" runat="server" onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
                      onClick="ServerSideMethod_Button_Click" />
```

If you answer OK to the popup server-side method will be executed, otherwise it will be skipped.

Thank you all for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It *is* a client-side solution you'll need. Given you want to both pop-up a message *and* disable the GUI/page underneath I'd recommend you take a look at modal dialogs. [JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) has provides de facto industry standard box, but others are available. Just Google it.